# Calculating a timeout that is suspended during certain periods

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, methods

I've been tasked with writing a method that calculates, given a start datetime and timeout in minutes, the datetime that the timeout should occur.

However the timeout should only 'tick' during certain times on certain days, which is determined by a non tick start datetime, non tick stop datetime and a list of open days.

For example, given the following:

- **Start datetime**: Friday 21/02/2014 15:00
- **Timeout**: 720 minutes (12 hours)
- **Open days**: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
- **Non tick start time**: 09:00
- **Non tick stop time**: 18:30

The calculated timeout datetime should be Monday 24/02/2014 17:30 (as it does not tick on Saturday and Sunday).

I'm writing this in C#, but its technically language agnostic.

Is there an 'elegant' way of doing this? Or is it simply a case of looping and adding additional time where its determined that timeout should stop ticking?

Comment: Does it make more sense to frame it as a countdown that only counts down during certain periods, rather than one that doesn't count during other periods?

Comment: Possibly, but its not something that runs all the time.  It wakes up every 5 mins or so, and calculates if it needs to do anything based on whether or not this 'timeout' datetime has passed or not

Comment: I've never even tried to do this, but you might want to take a look at the [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and write a custom calendar for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a timer to tick every period (e.g. every second), you can increment a number of ticks in the timer's callback handler.

I would approach in one of the following ways. Either I could run the callback every second no matter what, and in the callback I could check whether I'm suppose to increment or skip the increment for this period (inside the non-tick time period).

Otherwise, I could increment every time no matter what, and then have a check to see if the non-tick period is approaching and, if so, then adjust the timer's callback time to run the next callback *after* the non-tick time period has elapsed.

Comment: Could do, although its not something that runs all the time.  It wakes up every 5 mins or so, and calculates if it needs to do anything based on whether or not this 'timeout' datetime has passed yet or not